# Replace all cells in a dataframe which contain '...' with np.nan

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

How do I remove any cells in a pandas dataframe that contain **'...'**

I have tried:

```
energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...')
```

Which gives me a list of either `NaN` or `'True'`.

I want to replace the values at the same locations where energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...') = **'True'** with **np.NaN**

Could anybody give me a helping hand on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
mask = energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...') == True
energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'].mask(mask)

# equivalently
# energy.loc[mask, 'Energy Supply'] = np.nan
```

Comment: when I try the first option: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: when I try the second option: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: strange! not sure what to do

Comment: worked it out:  mask = energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...',na=False). This seems to work too! And thanks for your help!

Comment: mask = energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...') == True doesn't seem to work? However, mask = energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains('...',na=False) does seem to work :)